# Function Overriding not working in c++

Tags: c++, oop, overloading

```
class parent
{
  public:
    virtual void print()
    {
      printf("STUFF");
    }
};

class child : public parent
{
   public:
     virtual void print()
     {
        printf("other stuff");
     }
 };

 int main()
 {
    parent par = new child;
    par.print();
  }
```

When ever I try this, it always uses the parent function instead of the child function. I was trying to get it to use the child function instead.

Comment: because par is a parent type variable, your child will immediately casted to parent. If you want to call the child's function, use a pointer or reference to base class, like: `parent& par = new child ();`

Comment: `parent par = new child;` this line shouldn't compile

Comment: If your real code is something like `parent par = *(new child);`, then that's because you're copying the parent part of the object and discarding (and leaking) the `child` object you copied it from. If it's actually `parent * par = ...` and `parent->print()`, then you should see the child's override. Without seeing the code that you're actually compiling, we can't guess what's wrong with it.

Comment: By the way, this is *overriding*, not *overloading*. Overloading is when two functions *in the same scope* have the same name, but differ in some way. Overriding is when a derived class redefines a parent's virtual function.

Comment: when you use the new operator use the delete operator as well please.

Comment: The code doesn't compile. Please present the code that gives the error described in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class parent
{
public:
    virtual void print()
    {
        printf("STUFF");
    }
};

class child : public parent
{
public:
    virtual void print()
    {
        printf("other stuff");
    }
};

int main()
{
    parent *par = new child;
    par->print();
    delete par;
    par = NULL;
}
```

Comment: You just taught a newbie how _not_ to do memory management. Congratulations.

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 Did you seriously get mad because he used a pointer?

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 What's wrong with using a pointer?

Comment: @Andrew A pointer is fine, and in this context, necessary. Dynamic allocation is not necessary at all here though. And this answer teaches that it is. That is wrong. Period. Consult your C++ book for more information.

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 Why delete your comment? Consult a c++ book to determine why one shouldn't use `new`? Do you never use `new` in your c++ code?

Comment: @Andrew I didn't delete it; there's a lot of mod censorship at the moment

Comment: @Andrew No, you should not use `new`, but that's quite besides the point - you don't need dynamic allocation at all here, as I have already stated